# Quarkus Portable

Tags: windows, quarkus

Is there a way to use quarkus in Windows portable? Can I run `quarkus` command from a portable folder?

I tried to find a solution in quarkus.io but couldn't find any. My company has limitations to use choco, sdkman or WSL2; thats why I am wondering a solution.

Comment: Its just a jar so yes should be very doable. 

If you can use jbang you can use that too.

Is there anything that fails to work?